# Change default printer parameters with win32api.ShellExecute

Tags: python, winapi, printing

I learned that I can easily print a pdf file with this code in Python:

```
import win32api 
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print','test.pdf','.','/manualstoprint',0)
```

The result is that my default printer prints with default parameters the complete pdf file.
How can I print my pdf file changing default parameters (for example print on both sides, or print form page x to page y, or change paper format from A4 to A3)?

Comment: You probably can't expect to do this unless you control the program which is associated with the PDF extension

Comment: You mean that I should be able to control Acrobat Reader with Python? Could you tell me how I could learn this?

Comment: You need to try to research what command line arguments are supported by Acrobat Reader. I would expect that they are documented. This is actually not a question about Python, rather it is about your specific PDF program.